# Split a list into chunks with multiple integer delimiters

Tags: python, list

I have two list of integers, namely `numbers` and `delimiters`. I want to divide `numbers` into chunks divided by `delimiters`.

### Example:

```
numbers = [10, 13, 7, 204, 129, 44, 12, 7, 17, 49, 216, 43, 16, 7, 7, 38, 29, 76, 54, 17, 39, 7, 17, 77, 7, 24, 19]
delimiters = [7,17,77]
```

### Output:

```
result = [[10,13],[204, 129, 44, 12],[49, 216, 43, 16],[38, 29, 76, 54],[39],[24, 19]]
```

As already seen in the example, I want to split the list if I see one or multiple occurences of the `delimiter`.

I can easily do it by **a simple loop**, but I am sure there should be a *better*, probably more *Pythonic* way of doing it. I also feel like [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is the way to go, however, I couldn't find a good function that could fit to this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go, using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(numbers, delimiters.__contains__) if not k]
[[10, 13], [204, 129, 44, 12], [49, 216, 43, 16], [38, 29, 76, 54], [39], [24, 19]]
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for!